# Is there an R function for a frequency cross table?

Tags: r

I have a dataset looking like the following:

```
Class     Status   Name
History   teacher  A
History   student  B
History   student  C
Geo       teacher  A
Geo       student  C
Bio       teacher  B
Bio       student  C
```

and I would like to obtain a frequency cross-table (displaying the status of each person and the class where it happens)

```
Student\Teacher  A            B         C
A                   
B                History
C                History;Geo  Bio
```

The idea would be to try to measure how certain people tend to work together (how for example certain students want to study because of their professor or of the type of class), and how often they do each role. Everybody can be both teacher or student, depending on the class, some of them are never studying, the others are never teaching.

I tried different functions, especially the table() one, but I’m stumbling on the fact that I often have several pupils for one teacher and I cannot see who is working with whom.
Unfortunately, my dataset is really large so doing it by hand is really not possible.

I hope it was clear but of course let me know if I can be more precise.

Answer (score 0):

We can `group_by` 'Name', 'Status', `paste` the `unique` elements of 'Class' as a string, and `spread` from 'long' to 'wide' format

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(Name, Status) %>% 
  summarise(Class = str_c(unique(Class), collapse=";")) %>% 
  spread(Name, Class)
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#  Status  A           B       C              
#  <chr>   <chr>       <chr>   <chr>          
#1 student <NA>        History History;Geo;Bio
#2 teacher History;Geo Bio     <NA>
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Class = c("History", "History", "History", "Geo", 
"Geo", "Bio", "Bio"), Status = c("teacher", "student", "student", 
"teacher", "student", "teacher", "student"), Name = c("A", "B", 
"C", "A", "C", "B", "C")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Rearrange your data - using @akrun's data

```
L <- split(df1, df1$Status)
newdf <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by="Class", all=TRUE), L)
```

This is what it looks like

```
    Class Status.x Name.x Status.y Name.y
1     Bio  student      C  teacher      B
2     Geo  student      C  teacher      A
3 History  student      B  teacher      A
4 History  student      C  teacher      A
```

Use `tidyverse`

```
result <- newdf %>% 
              group_by(Name.x, Name.y) %>% 
              summarise(Class = paste(Class, collapse=';')) %>% 
              complete(Name.x = LETTERS[1:3], Name.y = LETTERS[1:3]) %>% 
              distinct() %>% 
              spread(Name.y, Class)
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   Name [3]
  Name  A           B     C
  <chr> <chr>       <chr> <chr>
1 A     NA          NA    NA
2 B     History     NA    NA
3 C     Geo;History Bio   NA
```